# IMAP date filter issue

Tags: imap

I am using IMAP command to download the Yahoo mails.Mails got download successfully.

But there is a 4 hours difference between the date shown by yahoo and the downloaded date.

Date shown by Yahoo---->Mon,30 Dec 2013 20:36

Date in downloaded mail---->31 Dec 2013 4:36 AM

---

Because of this the Search command for BEFORE,SINCE also get failed.

It gives me the wrong result.

Comment: Sounds like a timezone issue. One version shows the message in the sender's timezone, one shows the message in what it thinks is the reader's timezone. I suggest you investigate that.

Comment: Also, before and since use the `INTERNALDATE`, not the `Date:` header. Internal Date is usually in UTC.